# Where is /_layouts/15/SFS.Ashok.Refer/scripts folder located in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I'm editing a **JS** script file using SharePoint Designer and would like to upload it on to   `/_layouts/15/SFS.Ashok.Refer/scripts` .Where is the folder stored on the SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder isn't in SharePoint Designer (or more specifically, isn't inside the web/site collection) instead it is in 15 hive which is physically located here (and is shared with all the webs/site collections):

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15`

Comment: I don't have this location in my PC: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15`.

Comment: @Ngeshlew, are you looking on the SharePoint server's file system?

Comment: Yes this will exist on SharePoint server's file system only. If you don't have access to it, you might need to create a Visual Studio WSP solution to put your JavaScript files in 15 hive.

Comment: Guys, I am working on SharePoint Online. If it's possible to map the site, then I have not been able to do that.

Comment: Actually, it's under TEMPLATE. That is, `/_layouts` corresponds to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`.